# Erro Install Android Target - Cordova CLI

Tags: android, macos, cordova, command-line-interface

i am using Android SDK Studio with Command CLI of Cordova in my Mac Yosemite for developer a app, but i found that error para add platform android in my project.

Command executing: cordova platform add android

Error:

```
/Users/roni/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: Please install Android target "android-19".
Hint: Run "android" from your command-line to open the SDK manager.
    at /Users/roni/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:174:19
    at _fulfilled (/Users/roni/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/roni/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/roni/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
    at /Users/roni/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
    at flush (/Users/roni/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
Error: /Users/roni/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5)
```

My Configuration for Bash_profile

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/sdk/platform-tools:/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/sdk/tools
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `SDK  tools` & "SDK build" tools in Android SDK. With Eclipse ADT it looks like this image

[image]

Install the 19 package

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

Go to this directory

```
/Users/roni/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/framework
```

Edit `project.properties` file. Change `target` to `19`.

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system use,
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.

# Indicates whether an apk should be generated for each density.
split.density=false
# Project target.
target=android-19
apk-configurations=
renderscript.opt.level=O0
android.library=true
```

Restart your terminal.