# Cordova Android Versions supported

Tags: android, cordova

Cordova's [documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide) claims to support back to build 10 (Android 2.3), but if I use the Android SDK tool to load the Android development bits ("Sources for Android SDK", etc.) for a version before 19 (just tried 15, tried 10 previously), I get the error

```
[Error: Please install Android target "android-19".
Hint: Run "android" from your command-line to open the SDK manager.]
```

Is there something I'm missing or is the documentation lying?

Answer (score 3):

I think you don't really understand how sdk are configued in android projects. You have the target SDK and the min SDK.

Target-sdk designs which version of the API will be used to build the app.

Min-SDK designs the minimum version of android the app will be compatible with.

Cordova-lib needs SDK-19 to compile, if you're willing to use crosswalk-cordova, you would need sdk-21, but that does not mean your app won't work with android 2.3, as long as you keep min-sdk to 10. What it means is that your app may use API functions that are not avaible in older SDK versions.

I think the default value for minSDK is actually 10, but you can configure it in your project's config.xml:

```
    <platform name="android">
        <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="10" />
...
    </platform>
```

Comment: True, I am only just beginning to learn the first things about the Android environment, so thanks for the clarification. I did try what you say, and the running it on an older Android 2.3.3 phone gave me a load of error, perhaps related to local storage in the browser. Perhaps it's just that local storage doesn't work on the older phones or the SQL API is somehow different? More to research.

Comment: localstorage should be fine in 2.3.3. Haven't tried sqlite with it (are you using Cordova-SQLitePlugin?) but there are many other things that can cause issue with the old browser : css, html5, javascript. You can refer to http://caniuse.com/ about support in android 2.3.3

Answer (score 1):

You are having this issue right!! [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29062330/error-install-android-target-cordova-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29062330/erro-install-android-target-cordova-cli)

Update your `SDK  tools` & "SDK build" tools in Android SDK. With Eclipse ADT it looks like this image

[image]

Install the 19 package

Comment: I'm afraid I must have not worded my question well enough. I can get it to work perfectly fine with Version 19 and run the App on Android 4.4 devices. What i want is to build the App in such a way that it will launch and run on a Version 10 (Android 2.3) or at least 15 (Android 4.0.4) phone. When I try to do this, it does not work for me.

Comment: Things I have tried so far: setting  "android-targetSdkVersion" and/or "android-minSdkVersion" in the config.xml file, uninstalling the API=19 files using the android SDK package manager shown above and installing those for API=15.

Comment: I think uninstalling 19 build tools wasn't a good idea. Cordova has a dependency on build tools. simply changing this `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />` to `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />` or any configuration in the file here `Your_Project_Folder/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml` should work.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on location. That looks like PhoneGap syntax; will it work with Cordova? I can try. I did not, in fact, delete the Build tools, just the other SDK bits.

Comment: I use it with cordova

Comment: It should already be there in that file. you just need to adjust the values as you wanted

Answer (score 0):

Go to this directory

```
/Users/DevinCeartas/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/framework
```

Edit `project.properties` file. Change `target` to `19`.

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system use,
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.

# Indicates whether an apk should be generated for each density.
split.density=false
# Project target.
target=android-19
apk-configurations=
renderscript.opt.level=O0
android.library=true
```

Restart your terminal.

Comment: I'm afraid I must have not worded my question well enough. I can get it to work perfectly fine with Version 19 and run the App on Android 4.4 devices. What i want is to build the App in such a way that it will launch and run on a Version 10 (Android 2.3) or at least 15 (Android 4.0.4) phone. When I try to do this, it does not work for me.

Comment: Though knowing where this setting is looks interesting. I will try setting that to 15 or 10 now.