# Cordova build require SDK Platform

Tags: android, cordova, ubuntu

I'm on Ubuntu, I installed cordova, cordova cli, android studio and all the packages but when I try to build my app I recive the following error:

```
Running command: /home/admin/Desktop/hello/platforms/android/cordova/build 
[Error: Please install Android target: "android-21".

Hint: Open the SDK manager by running: /opt/android-sdk/tools/android
You will require:
1. "SDK Platform" for android-21
2. "Android SDK Platform-tools (latest)
3. "Android SDK Build-tools" (latest)]
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /home/admin/Desktop/hello/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /home/admin/Desktop/hello/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

Note: I added the path for android-sdk in bashrc:

```
#AndroidDev PATH

export PATH=${PATH}:${HOME}/android-sdk-linux/tools

export PATH=${PATH}:${HOME}/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having this issue right!! [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29062330/error-install-android-target-cordova-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29062330/erro-install-android-target-cordova-cli)

Update your `SDK  tools` & "SDK build" tools in Android SDK. With Eclipse ADT it looks like this image

[image]

Install the 21 package as your version of cordova is expecting package 21

Comment: I dont understand, I have all installed

Comment: So any other sugestion?

Comment: Do you have SDK build tools 21 installed? As per this `Please install Android target: "android-21"` it's not installed with your SDK.